# Is my constraint the limiting factor in my upsert?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I currently have a table named `prefixes`. This table has `prefix` with `BIGINT`, and `guild` with `BIGINT UNIQUE`. My query is such:
`INSERT INTO prefixes VALUES ($1, $2) ON CONFLICT (prefixes.guild) DO UPDATE SET "prefix" = $2 WHERE "guild" = $1;` where `$1` and `$2` is `14865` and `'~'` respectively. (my library does allow this syntax.

it currently fails with `AmbiguousColumnError: column reference "guild" is ambiguous`.

Would the `unique` constraint be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but in the `WHERE` clause, there is a choice between `prefixes.guild` and `EXCLUDED.guild`, where the latter stands for the value that was intended to be inserted.  So you'd have to say which one you mean:

```
WHERE prefixes.guild = $1
```

But that is altogether unnecessary, because the `UPDATE` will only affect the one matched row anyway, and you should omit the whole redundant `WHERE` clause.